# why is droppable not accepting the item being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Why is the jQuery droppable not accepting the item being dropped? I don't want to use sortable anywhere.

```js
$(function() {
 $(".item").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
 });
 $("#drop").droppable({
  accept:".item"
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
<div id="drop"> </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it does work:

```js
$(function() {
 $(".item,.letter ").draggable({
  helper: "clone"
 });
 $("#drop").droppable({
  accept:".item",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          alert("dropped")
        }
    });  
});
```

```css
#drop {
  border:1px dashed gray;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.items * {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding:3px 0;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="items">
  <div class="letter">a</div>
  <div class="letter">b</div>
  <div class="letter">c</div>
  <div class="letter">d</div>
  <div class="letter">e</div>
  <div class="letter">f</div>
</div>
<div id="drop"> </div>
```

it is accepting it, but items are not staying there. If you want the clone to stay there you need to append it to your container like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".item,.letter ").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
 $("#drop").droppable({
  accept:".item",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $("#drop .item").addClass("dropped");
            $(".dropped").removeClass("ui-draggable item");
            $(".dropped").draggable({
                containment: 'parent',
                grid: [80,76]
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

```css
#drop {
  border:1px dashed gray;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.items *, .dropped {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding:3px 0;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
<div id="drop"> </div>
```

of course you can achieve a lot of behaviors, for example this other one:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".item,.letter ").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
 $("#drop").droppable({
  accept:".item",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $("#drop .item").addClass("dropped");
            $(".dropped").removeClass("ui-draggable item");
            $(".dropped").draggable();
        }
    });  
});
```

```css
#drop {
  border:1px dashed gray;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.items *, .dropped {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding:3px 0;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
<div id="drop"> </div>
```

Comment: Yes It is accepting it. But the item being dragged is not staying there!
Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mx0mqov4/1/
I do want the clone property but want the element dragged to stay in droppable area.

Comment: Superb .. Thanks alot !